Can you Ready a Bonus Action (2024)?
The Ready action allows you to act out of your turn using a Reaction:

You take the Ready action ... on your turn, which lets you act by taking a Reaction before the start of your next turn. ... you choose the action you will take ... or you choose to move up to your Speed ... (emphasis mine)

An Action is consumed during the player's turn, and a Reaction is consumed when the act is triggered. However, the emphasized term "action" may lead to some confusion. It could equivocally refer to:

Action (capitalized), denoting a specific part of the action economy within a turn.
The general English meaning of "action."
A category action, which includes the technical, first sense but is narrower than the general meaning.

There are several reasons to prefer the third interpretation, action. First, the Player's Handbook (PHB) uses capitalization to indicate technical terms like Action, Bonus Action, Reaction, etc. Reference to the narrow, technical sense of Action can be found throughout the PHB:

The Action table lists the game’s main actions...

"Action" here, is capitalized, while "actions" is not. Notably, Bonus Actions are not listed on the table.
Additionally, the tag, Action is used to indicate inclusion in a category or rules.

Some entries have a tag in brackets after the entry’s name, as in “Attack [Action].” A tag—Action... indicates that a rule is part of a family of rules.

Second, the rules for Bonus Actions refer to them as "actions":

A Bonus Action is a special action that you can take...

This seems to qualify Bonus Actions for the Ready action, regardless of capitalization, insofar as they are a type of action.
Lastly, both of the above passages define their technical terms in reference to a less technical term, action.
It is reasonable to conclude that the the Ready action rules use "action" in a categorical sense, and to conclude that category includes Actions and Bonus Actions. So, it appears that Bonus Actions may be readied, but the language is a bit ambiguous.

@Raj, this is a question about dnd-5e-2024, not dnd-5e-2014, to which that link refers.

Great question and well argued. I came in assuming you'd be wrong, but your argument is pedantically sound. You should consider clarifying that you are aware that "To be readied, a spell must have a casting time of an action", thus forbidding any Bonus Action spells. To me this specification strongly implies that other types of explicit Bonus Actions are also forbidden, but as you argue, it's not stated so we can't take it for granted!

You cannot Ready a Bonus Action
Per the basic rules for 5E-2024 (emphasis added):

A Bonus Action is a special action that you can take on the same turn that you take an action. You can’t take more than one Bonus Action on a turn, and you have a Bonus Action to take only if a rule explicitly says so. See also chapter 1 (“Actions”).

Since a Ready-ed action isn't on your turn, and it's explicitly "the action" not some combination of actions, you're not eligible to take a bonus action.
That said, when you take the Ready action, you have taken an action on your turn (Ready itself being an action), so if you have Bonus Actions available to you that are compatible with the Ready action (e.g. don't require you to attack on your turn or the like), you could take a Bonus Action on your turn and take the Ready action to act off-turn.

I'll also note that the rules are not nearly so careful about distinguishing "Action" from "action" as you assume. By default, it looks like "action" has the meaning you ascribe to "Action", unless otherwise specified. For example, the Incapacitated condition is described as:

Inactive. You can’t take any action, Bonus Action, or Reaction.

If "action" in lower case was a general term that encompassed the "special actions" of Bonus Action and Reactions, there'd be no need to be so explicit.
AFAICT, in neither the glossary, nor the Actions chapter, do they ever capitalize "Action" unless it's the header for a section or table (or referring to said section(s)/table explicitly), the beginning of a sentence (both cases where English capitalizes things normally), or paired with "Bonus". It's never capitalized on its own, mid-sentence. Unless the actual PHB (which I don't have yet) differs dramatically here, there is no capital-A "Action" in the new edition at all; action means your regular action by default, and can only mean "special actions" of some sort in the appropriate context.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
